# grandtotal is not caliculates for dynamic rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
var grandtotal=0;

function startCalc(event){
    var el=event.target;
    var parent=el.parentNode.parentNode;
    var price=parent.querySelectorAll('input[name="price"]')[0];
    var disc=parent.querySelectorAll('input[name="disc"]')[0];
    var out=parent.querySelectorAll('span[data-name="tot"]')[0];
    var tot=parseFloat( price.value ) * parseInt( disc.value );
    var subtot=parseFloat( price.value )-parseInt( tot );

    grandtotal+=subtot;

    out.innerHTML=subtot;
}
```

from above code i am not able to getting grandtotal of all rows.it only takes subtotal of a particular row and assigns to grandtotal.looping is not working.please help me to come out of this.

Comment: Post your HTML code for `price`,`disc` and `tot`

Comment: It looks like you're setting only `subtot` to the DOM, `grandtotal` is never used ..?

Comment: i have declared but not mentioned here.actually what my problem is if i give discount to first product it caliculates subtotal and gives the same result in grandtotal field also.but  if i give discount to second product it caliculate subtotal and grandtotal is caliculated for first and second rows and so on....